# Java Boolean In 'IF' Statement Not Functioning

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, statements

Unfortunately the snippet of code below is not functioning as it should. It's attached to a JLabel so that when clicked, notices whether PlayerOne or PlayerTwo is playing, and re-arranges their boolean values accordingly

[ex: When mouseClicked:If playerOne is true, then do something, and set playerOne to false and playerTwo to true].

So, it swaps their values when mouseClicked is activated!

```
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(playerOne = true){
                playerOne = false;
                playerTwo = true;
                boxOne.setIcon(xIcon);                  
            } else { if(playerTwo = true){
                playerOne = true;
                playerTwo = false;
                boxOne.setIcon(oIcon);
            }}
```

Thanks in advance,
Tom!

Comment: My opinion is that all syntax errors (this one does qualify) should be closed as too localised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java the operand to test equality between two items is == not '=' which is an assignment; an assignment returns the assigned value, so your :

```
if (playerOne = true)
```

will always be true as playerOne will be assigned to `true`, then the if will become `if (true)` and the statement associated will always be executed.

the best way to refactor your code is:

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if(playerOne) {
            playerOne = false;
            playerTwo = true;
            boxOne.setIcon(xIcon);                  
        } else if(playerTwo) {
            playerOne = true;
            playerTwo = false;
            boxOne.setIcon(oIcon);
       }
    }
```

as the `something == true` would be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(playerTwo = true)
```

`==` not `=`.

Wouldn't it be simpler to have a "currentPlayer" integer that is either 1 or 2 instead though? This would also prevent the (presumably impossible) state of having both players active at once.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment here

```
if (playerTwo = true)
```

replace with

```
if (playerTwo == true)
```

or better

```
if (playerTwo)
```